# HTML button running out of alignment

Tags: php, html, css, alignment

My idea is very simple, I will have a search box and a submit button.

When user key in the keyword and click on the submit button, results will be shown below with an **additional button**. Now my problem is I have no idea on how to make the button to be located at bottom right of the table populated.

Please consider the below code for my situation:

```
<input type="text" name="criteriaInput" style="width: 300px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO" />

    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['inquiryMethod'])){
            error_reporting(0);
            $sql = 'SELECT 
                        *
                    FROM 
                        table
                    WHERE
                        fullname REGEXP \''.$_POST['criteriaInput'].'\'' ;
            $server = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
            $db =  mysql_select_db("mysql",$server);
            $query = mysql_query($sql);

            echo "<table class=\"striped\">";
            echo    "<tr class=\"header\">";
            echo        "<td>Full Name</td>";
            echo        "<td>ID</td>";
            echo        "<td>ID Type</td>";
            echo        "<td>Issuance Country</td>";
            echo        "<td>Class</td>";
            echo     "</tr>";
                   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                       echo "<tr>";
                       echo "<td>".$row[fullname]."</td>";
                       echo "<td>".$row[id]."</td>";
                       echo "<td>".$row[id_type]."</td>";
                       echo "<td>".$row[issuance_country]."</td>";
                       echo "<td>{$row['class']}</td>";
                       echo "</tr>";
                   }
            echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"CIF_InquiryAction.php\">";
            echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"create\" value=\"Create\" />";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "</table>";
        }else{
            echo "Please select one of the criteria!";
        }
    }

    ?>
```

The submit button with value "Create" did successfully created on existence of data, however it's aligned on top left of the table.
Kindly advice Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your button into a table row and cell.

```
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td colspan=\"5\">"
 echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"CIF_InquiryAction.php\">";
 echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"create\" value=\"Create\" />";
 echo "</form>";
 echo "</td>"
 echo "</tr>";
```

Also, your form should probably move to be outside your table.

Editing to show input outside of table:

```
 echo "</table>";
 echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"create\" value=\"Create\" />";
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, although now the button is located bottom right of the table, but it looks like part of the table. Is that possible to make it like the button is separated on it's own?

Comment: Yes, just put the input information after the closing table tag.

Comment: put the form around the table & input like so: <form><table></table><input/></form>